# How can I use Spring Data MongoDB to rename a string field and change it to an array?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I have the following [`updateMany`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/) MongoDB command which renames a field and converts it from a string to a single element array.  It's runnable in the [MongoDB Shell (`mongosh`)](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/), and uses an aggregation pipeline-based update:

```javascript
db.example.updateMany({"outer.oldField": {$in: ["B", "C"]}}, [
        {$set: {"outer.newField": ["$outer.oldField"]}},
        {$unset: "outer.oldField"}
]);
```

I am trying to convert this to Spring Data Mongo using [`MongoTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html), [which supports](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo-template.aggregation-update) aggregation pipeline updates.  However, the documentation and online examples are sparse.  I've tried a few different approaches, and haven't had success translating this to something that works with `MongoTemplate`.

Here's an attempt, which does not work:

```java
mongoOperations.updateMulti(
        Query.query(Criteria.where("outer.oldField").in("B", "C")),
        AggregationUpdate.update()
                .set("outer.newField").toValueOf(ArrayOperators.arrayOf("[$outer.oldField]"))
                .unset("outer.oldField"),
        "example"
)
```

How can I translate the given `mongosh` update query to a Spring Data Mongo operation on `MongoTemplate`?

## Example data

Example data:

```javascript
db.createCollection("example");
db.example.insertOne({outer: {oldField: "A"}});
db.example.insertOne({outer: {oldField: "A"}});
db.example.insertOne({outer: {oldField: "B"}});
db.example.insertOne({outer: {oldField: "C"}});
```

Result of `updateMany`:

```
> db.example.find()

[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("64839132bd73e957955e3029"),
    outer: { oldField: 'A' }
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("64839132bd73e957955e302a"),
    outer: { oldField: 'A' }
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("64839132bd73e957955e302b"),
    outer: { newField: [ 'B' ] }
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("64839133bd73e957955e302c"),
    outer: { newField: [ 'C' ] }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use this query to convert your field to array.

```
mongoOperations.updateMulti(
    Query.query(Criteria.where("outer.oldField").in("B", "C")),
    AggregationUpdate.update()
        .set("outer.newField").toValue(List.of("$outer.oldField"))
        .unset("outer.oldField"),
    "example"
);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I've confirmed that this works as desired.  I guess that also means if I had a variable string in an aggregation update, I'd have to be careful to escape it so that it wouldn't be interpreted as e.g. a field reference ("$outer.oldField").

Comment: Correct. You need to be careful of when to use toValue and when to use toValueOf

Comment: Unless I screwed something up, from my own experimentation it looks like `toValue` and `toValueOf` both have the same in this regard.  The [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/AggregationUpdate.SetValueAppender.html) aren't super clear to me, but maybe the only difference is that `toValueOf` knows how to handle `AggregationExpression` and `Field` values, in addition to direct values?